# PostORder Traversal to compute disk space

Tags: tree, postorder

I have read that one of the applications of postorder traversal in trees is to compute disk space. Why can't we use preorder traversal? Won't we get the same answer?

Answer (score 0):

Post order means you process current node after you process whole subtree (all childern) of this node.

And thats exactly what you do when you compute the disk space. You start with c:\, then you recursively compute the size of c:\Users, then size of c:\Program Files, ... and c:\Windows, and after all you computer the the size of c:\ by summing the size of subfolders. You can not compute the size of c:\ before you process all subfolders...